# Building a native MacOS Ethereum app

Tags: mac-osx

What is the best way of designing a native Ethereum app on MacOS. My initial thought was have the native MacOS app be the frond end and have it talk to the geth daemon which will do the heavy lifting. Is that the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/docs/) a javascript library to wrap you're App into a cross-platform Application (Linux-MacOX-Windows).

[Here](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate) a boilerplate useful to start.

Comment: I’m not looking for a cross platform solution. How does electron make integration of ethereum easier in a native Mac app?

Comment: First ask, and after give a negative feedback. Good luck.